# Running Linux executables in R using WSL

Tags: r, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have exhaustively tried to get the program to compile properly on Windows, but it has been a futile struggle. However, Linux seems to handle it just fine. Using Ubuntu on WSL and running `make`, I get an executable which I can run in bash with `./`. I would like to use this and call it in R, though I am not sure if this is possible. I can do this using a Windows executable by doing `system()`, however, this does not seem to translate to a Linux executable. Is there a proper way to call a Linux executable inside an R script?

Comment: Run a Linux R on WSL, and use `system()`?  I am not aware of Windows programs being able to directly execute anything inside WSL.

Comment: Of course, that assumes you don't want to just shift the whole workload to a native Linux machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a Linux binary in WSL from the Windows environment, use the `wsl` commandline utility. In R, that would look like

```r
system2("wsl", "your_binary --arg1 --arg2 ...")
```